# PYTHON file updates not reflecting when imported in VCSCODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, python-import

I have 2 files. One called add_numbers.py. In there I have the following code:

```
def increase_number(num):
  return num +10
```

And then I have a 2nd file, my main file, where I import the function as follows:

```
from add_numbers import increase_number

increase_number(3)
```

When I update *add_numbers.py* , to say, `return num + 20` , AND THEN SAVE IT, those changes are not showing in the main file i.e it still uses the old value, 10 and returns 13 instead of returing 23..unless I close and reopen vscode

Any suggestions? vscode bug maybe or how im importing the function?

***EDIT***

I am using ipykernel and the updates seem to reflecting after restarting the kernel

Comment: I doubt a bug like this in VS code, if you run the main file from the console does it gives you the same problem?

Comment: save it and open explorer and reopen that file to check saving

Comment: @tia.milani when i run the main file from the console, the changes reflect. Normally I run the files using ipykernel cells..so must be a problem with that then?

Comment: @Seonghun checked, the file definitely saves

Comment: I have a similar issue but with classes instead of functions and the issue persists even in console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this and also using ***ipykernel***, you have to restart the kernel each time you update a module for the changes to reflect